# I have got issue when using Subject in rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

[image]

I am getting the issue when using Subject in rxjs.
It give error when i give type string to Subject

```
Expected 0 type arguments, but got 1
```

Comment: Insert the code in text format. Do not use pictures of code.

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + P -> Reload window. The IDE may blocked. The import looks good, the initialization is also good. What Rx version do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You should always initialize the subject inside the constructor,

Declare the variable as,

```
private _sourceSubject: Subject<string>;
```

and inside the constructor,

```
this._sourceSubject = new Subject<string>();
```